# Confusion on Execution of Asynchronous method inside the Synchronous method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

This might be answered somewhere but want to understand the detailed execution for this scenario. Today, I came across MVC action(synchronous) method which is calling an asynchronous method. I don't want this execution to wait synchronously or asynchronously. So, I haven't used the await keyword or wait method. But the outcome has surprised me a lot. Async method got executed some portion and some just skipped the execution. I have reproduced the same scenario and which is also behaving the same. Now, I got the execution but want to understand why this async and method behaving random execution inside the synchronous method. I have pasted the code snippet and output this code.

```
    internal async Task<int> Method1Async()
    {
        //await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Method 1 : Before Calling await");
        await Task.FromResult(5);
        //await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Method 1 : After Calling await");
        return await Task.FromResult(1);
    }

    internal async Task<int> Method2Async()
    {
        //await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Method 2 : Before Calling await");
        var res = await Method1Async();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Method 2 : After Calling await");
        return res;
    }

    internal async Task<int> Method3Async()
    {
        //await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Method 3 : Before Calling await");
        var res = await Method2Async();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Method 3 : After Calling await");
        return res;
    }

    internal void Method4()
    {
        Method3Async();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Main : Before calling Method4");
        var demo =  new Demo();
        demo.Method4();
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Main : After calling Method4");
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @mjwills Console.Writeline statements from Method 2 and 3 did not executed.

Comment: Somewhere I feel CLR should be responsible to execute these remaining portion of code.

Comment: You reached the end of your `Main` method. The program closed - it _stopped running_. You want to _not_ wait for the async code to execute, but you also want the console to be written to. You can't have both. Pick one.

Comment: There _was_ a warning in the IDE. You ignored it. `CS4014 Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.`.

Comment: If you missed I came across this in web app only and then tried to reproduce it in console app.

Comment: I have checked this answer and this all looks like console app and feel reasonable but what for web app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want this execution to wait synchronously or asynchronously. So, I haven't used the await keyword or wait method.

"Fire and forget" on ASP.NET is dangerous, as you have discovered.

Technically, "fire and forget" means "forget". If you fire off a task without waiting synchronously or asynchronously, then your code is explicitly saying it doesn't care when that task completes, or how it completes, or if it completes.

> Async method got executed some portion and some just skipped the execution... Now, I got the execution but want to understand why this async and method behaving random execution inside the synchronous method.

The bottom line is that shutdowns are normal. If you send a response to an HTTP request, then as far as ASP.NET knows, that request has been handled; and if there are no other requests, then it is safe to shut down. Fire-and-forget code is request-extrinsic (outside the scope of an HTTP request), so ASP.NET isn't even aware that that code exists.

> I feel CLR should be responsible to execute these remaining portion of code.

Nope. The CLR can't do this because that would prevent some use cases regarding `Task.WhenAny`.

If you need to return early, the [*proper* solution](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html) is:

1. Add a durable queue to your architecture. E.g., an Azure Queue.
2. Add a separate background processor to your architecture. E.g., an Azure Function.

Then, when your ASP.NET app wants to return early, it should serialize the work it needs to do into a message and write that to the durable queue, and *then* return. The separate background processor should read messages from the queue and do the actual work.

Comment: I agree with whatever you explained and thanks for the clarification. Somehow still not convinced with warning message. I feel it should have been updated.

Comment: `I feel it should have been updated` How would you have updated it? It specifically tells you the issue and how to avoid it.